# Perform multiple survival analysis with loop in R

Tags: r, loops, survival-analysis

I am recently working on survival analysis with R. I have two data frames, geneDf for gene expression, survDf for the follow-up. As the following samples:

```
#Data frame:geneID  
geneID=c("EGFR","Her2","E2F1","PTEN")
patient1=c(12,23,56,23)
patient2=c(23,34,11,6)
patient3=c(56,44,32,45)
patient4=c(23,64,45,23)
geneDf=data.frame(patient1,patient2,patient3,patient4,geneID)
> geneDf
  patient1 patient2 patient3 patient4 geneID
1       12       23       56       23   EGFR
2       23       34       44       64   Her2
3       56       11       32       45   E2F1
4       23        6       45       23   PTEN
#Data frame:survDf
ID=c("patient1","patient2","patient3","patient4")
time=c(23,7,34,56)
status=c(1,0,1,1)
survDf=data.frame(ID,time,status)
#    
> survDf
        ID time status
1 patient1   23      1
2 patient1    7      0
3 patient1   34      1
4 patient1   56      1
```

I extract the expression data of  specific gene from geneDf, and use the median of its expression as cut off value to perform survival analysis by “survival”package, and gain the p value by survdiff. In the following codes I use "EGFR" gene as an example.

```
#extract expression of a certain gene
targetGene<-subset(geneDf,grepl("EGFR",geneDf$geneID))
targetGene$geneID<-NULL
#Transpose the table and adjust its format
targetGene<-t(targetGene[,1:ncol(targetGene)])
targetGene<-data.frame(as.factor(rownames(targetGene)),targetGene)
colnames(targetGene)<-c("ID","Expression")
rownames(targetGene)<-NULL
targetGene$Expression1<-targetGene$Expression
 targetGene$Expression1[ targetGene$Expression<median( targetGene$Expression)]<-1
targetGene$Expression1[ targetGene$Expression>=median( targetGene$Expression)]<-2
#Survival analysis
library(survival)
##Add survival object
survDf$SurvObj<-with(survDf, Surv(time,status==1))
## Kaplan-Meier estimator for stage
km<-survfit(SurvObj~targetGene$Expression1, data=survDf, conf.type = "log-log")
sdf<-survdiff(Surv(time, status) ~targetGene$Expression1, data=survDf)
#gain p value
p.val <-1-pchisq(sdf$chisq, length(sdf$n) - 1)
> p.val
[1] 0.1572992
```

I can do this through different genes one by one. But the question is:  There are more than 10,000 gene need to be analyzed. I want gain all the p-values of them and put them to a new data frame. Do I need use loop or apply?

Comment: You first need to clarify your statistical methods. By making indicator variables at the median you are loosing a large amount of information and you have no correction for the multiple comparisons. Seek competent statistical help before spending further effort on a strategy that is virtually guaranteed to yield garbage.

Comment: Thank BondedDust's comment very much! Acturally, I am using  these two data frames to select some candidate genes for further research. So,it's the first step of a program.  Using median as indicator  is a reasonable method to choose candidates which will be validated in future experiment. Now, I really need for help to finish the above-mentioned multiple analyses.

Answer (score -1):

This is an ugly scritp but working.

In the Data10, in the first column you need to have the time, in the second one the status and in the next any treatments that you want.(patients as rownames)

```
loopsurff<-function(Data10){combos<-
rbind.data.frame(rep(1,ncol(Data10)- 2),
rep(2,ncol(Data10)-2),rep(3:(ncol(Data10)-2),1))
combos<-as.matrix(sapply(combos, as.numeric));library(plyr);
library(survival) 
vv<-adply(combos, 2, function(x) {
fit <-survdiff(Surv(Data10[,1], Data10[,2]) ~ Data10[, x[3]],data=Data10)
p<-1 - pchisq(fit$chisq, 1)
out <- data.frame("var1"=colnames(Data10)[x[3]],"p.value" =   
as.numeric(sprintf("%.3f", p)))
return(out)  
})
}`
```

You will get a data frame with the column names of yourdata[,3:ncol(yourdata)] and the p value to each one.